# How to compare two HTML files in python and print only the differences?

Tags: python, html, comparison

I have two HTML reports generated from sonar showing the issues in my code.

Problem Statement: I need to compare two sonar reports and find out the differences i.e. new issues that got introduced. Basically need to find differences in html and print those differences only.

I tried a few things:

```
import difflib
file1 = open('sonarlint-report.html', 'r').readlines()
file2 = open('sonarlint-report_latest.html', 'r').readlines()

htmlDiffer = difflib.HtmlDiff()
htmldiffs = htmlDiffer.make_file(file1, file2)

with open('comparison.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(htmldiffs)
```

Now this gives me a comparison.html which is nothing but two html diff. Doesn't print only the different lines.

Should I try HTML parsing and then somehow get the differences only to be printed?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `difflib.Differ`, you can keep only the difference lines and by filtering with the two letter codes that get written on every line. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ):

> **class difflib.Differ**
>
> This is a class for comparing sequences of lines
> of text, and producing human-readable differences or deltas. Differ
> uses SequenceMatcher both to compare sequences of lines, and to
> compare sequences of characters within similar (near-matching) lines.
>
> Each line of a Differ delta begins with a two-letter code:
>
> Code  Meaning
>
> '- '  line unique to sequence 1
>
> '+ '  line unique to sequence 2
>
> '  '  line common to both sequences
>
> '? '  line not present in either inputsequence
>
> Lines beginning with ‘?’ attempt to guide the eye to intraline
> differences, and were not present in either input sequence. These
> lines can be confusing if the sequences contain tab characters

By keeping the lines started with '- ' and '+ ' just the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to iterate through each html file line by line and checking to see if the lines are the same.

```
with open('file1.html') as file1, open('file2.html') as file2:
    for file1Line, file2Line in zip(file1, file2):
        if file1Line != file2Line:
            print(file1Line.strip('\n'))
            print(file2Line.strip('\n'))
```

You'll have to deal with newline characters and multiple line differences in a row, but this is probably a good start :)

Comment: This would be I think not efficient tho for large `html` files but the way to check it seems fine.